Autodesk Platform Services Viewer v7.98 - NOP_VIEWER.isolate() and/or NOP_VIEWER.isolate(null) no longer clears isolation
NOP_VIEWER's isolate() method no longer clears the isolation of specified dbids in v7.98.  Reading the new function used, it suggests passing in null now, which doesn't work either.
It also has a variable to pass in for the model, which I also tried, and still didn't work.  Any other suggestions on what to try?  For now, I've reverted back to v7.97 and it works perfectly fine.

This is being looked into. In the meantime you could use isolate([])

Things have been fixed in v7.99 and also a new function was added that makes it easier to isolate in a multi model environment: setAggregateIsolation
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/

I appreciate it, @AdamNagy!  Working again.
